# Javascript/jQuery set global variable of an unknown element

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

**EDIT**

TO BE DELETED. Issue was not code based but the global variable help was greatly appreciated and I did learn a lot.

How would you set a Global variable of an unknown element.

I need to pass a variable when an element is clicked to the rest of the functions in my code.  I know I am somewhat close. I just need a bit of help.
My code is below.  I am trying to pass my 'sampleName' and 'samplePath' to the 'loadPage' function only when an element is clicked.

```
(function ($) {
//Original Variables
//var sampleName = 'Book1'
//    samplePath = '/Book1/'

//Want dynamic variables
var sampleName;
var samplePath;
$(document).on("click", ".sampleDiv", function (event) {
    sampleName = $(this).attr("sample") || '';
    samplePath = 'Books/' + sampleName;
    //alert(sampleName);
   // alert(samplePath);

});//End click


function loadPage(page) {

    var img = $('<img />');
    img.load(function () {
        var container = $('.Book .p' + page);
        img.css({ width: '100%', height: '100%' });
        img.appendTo($('.Book .p' + page));
        container.find('.loader').remove();
    });

    img.attr('src', samplePath + 'pages/' + page + '.jpg');

}
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance.

**/EDIT/**

Hmmm. I must be asking this the wrong way.
More explanation.
Originally my code had 2 variable set statically. 
Example:

```
 var sampleName = 'Book1',
     samplePath = '/Book1/'
```

What I am trying to do is make those variables more dynamic and set them when the

```
<div sample='Book1'></div>
```

is clicked on the variables (mainly the 'Book1' part) changes.  Each 'Book' will have a different number (Book1, Book2, Book3, etc).  I want to make the variables get set depending on which one gets clicked on. The attr("sample") on my DIV will determine the Book number.  So when the DIV is clicked on the attr("sample") will be the variable's value.

Hope this helps with my issue in explaining more.

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/RBq7W/) for me.

Comment: The issue is actually in the 'loadPage' function. You will see the img.src.  The samplePath is not getting passed from my click to the loadPage function.  At least I can't get it to alert there anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all your global variables outside of your function.

```
var sampleName;
var samplePath;    
(function ($) {


$(document).on("click", ".sample", function (event) {
    sampleName = $(this).attr("sample") || '';
    samplePath = 'Books/' + sampleName;
    //alert(sampleName);
   // alert(samplePath);

});//End click
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is GLOBAL, it must be declared OUTSIDE the (function ($) {
.. ex:

```
var sampleName;
var samplePath;

(function ($) {
  ...

})(jQuery);
```